# Element size in EhCache

Tags: ehcache

I've setup a simple cache, using an `Integer` for the key and a `Double` for the value. After populating the cache, the ratio `cache.calculateInMemorySize() / cache.getMemoryStoreSize()` is constant at 344 bytes per element. I expect overhead, but my payload is (32 + 64) 96 bits, or 12 bytes, so the overhead is a whopping 332 bytes - or am I completely misunderstanding how this work? If not, what, if anything, can I do to bring down the overhead?

The cache is meant to be a memory-only store. We want to fit everything in there, so overflow and expiry is not needed, and as we can populate fairly quickly from the external data source (just not fast enough to use it as the primary data source), persistence is not needed either.

Using version 2.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the payload is the things actually being cached. Are you including the size of the keys as well? I believe the calculateInMemorySize also includes the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements:

> The cache is meant to be a memory-only store. We want to fit
>   everything in there, so overflow and expiry is not needed, and as we
>   can populate fairly quickly from the external data source (just not
>   fast enough to use it as the primary data source), persistence is not
>   needed either.

I conclude that you don't need to use any 3rd party caching framework at all. Instead you can get away with simple HashMap...since your cached elements never expire and always fit in memory. Also, you will not to include EhCache jars in your classpath and load its classes!

Here is sample code:

```
public class MyCustomCache
{
  private Map<Integer, Double> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();

  public Double getCachedValueByKey(Integer key)
  {
    return myMap.get(key);
  }

  public void putValue2Cache(Integer key, Double value)
  {
    myMap.put(key, value);
  }

  public Double removeValueFromCache(Integer key)
  {
    return myMap.remove(key);
  }
}
```